# Cannot upload *.MAF file to SharePoint library

Tags: document-library, file-upload

We're trying to upload an *.MAF file (Microsoft Access Form Shortcut) to a SharePoint 2010 library. Is there a way to change the restricted files to allow this file to be uploaded? Thanks.

Comment: I think I found the answer: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262496.aspx -- at the very bottom of that page it has the steps to change restricted file extensions. Sorry for being too quick on the trigger to post the question :) Feel free to delete it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the answer: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262496.aspx

1. In Central Administration, click Security.
2. On the Security page, in the General Security section, click Define blocked file types.
3. On the Blocked File Types page, if you want to change the selected Web application, on the Web Application menu, click Change Web Application. Use the Select Web Application page to select a Web application.
4. To stop blocking a file type, select a file type from the list, press the Delete key, and then click OK. Add a file type to block it.